# Forum/website integration - suggestions needed

Tags: php, forum, integrate

I have my existing website with a basic users table and all that. I was wondering if you have any idea about a forum I could install which will be of good quality but I can use the current members in my database on it.

It would also help if there was a simple or not too hard way for transferring the current users to the forum users database.

What I was thinking was when the users registers on the main site he/she also gets added to the forum users database. I use double md5 hash so I need to make sure I can change the forum hash easily for the login page.

A simple or easy to follow method is preferred.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think this probably belongs on the software recommendations community http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [MyBB](http://www.mybb.com/) or [Phorum](http://www.phorum.org/) open source PHP scripts, but it depends what features do you require from your forum script. Using current members in your databse should be easy.

Comment: I just want a good forum script like phpBB but simple to integrate

Comment: MyBB is very similar to phpBB, in my opinion easier to integrate. Although at this level of forum scripts, it will always take some time.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions or easy to follow tutorials I could use?